# Installer unable to continue?

Tags: 10.10, installation, ubiquity

I am trying to install Ubuntu 10.10 on to my laptop (Toshiba 64bit, with Windows 7 and Mint 8 already in it).

However, for several times now when I try to install the new OS, it cannot go further than the second screen where it has all boxes ticked (as OK). The activity indicator just goes on like forever!

Any idea/help as to why?

Answer (score 5):

At that point in the install, it's installing the Broadcom wireless driver and preparing the partitioning operations.  Both of these tasks are complex and thus require a moderate amount of CPU time.

If you do not check the box for third-party software, it will progress to the next screen much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have capital letters in your username? There's a bug in the installer: you are not alerted that capital letters are not allowed, but you cannot proceed until you've got all lowercase letters.

[Installer gets stuck with a grayed out forward button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14168/live-cd-installer-gets-stuck-with-a-grayed-out-forward-button)