# Installer won't let me continue, forward and skip buttons greyed out

Tags: 10.10, installation, ubiquity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Live CD installer gets stuck with a grayed out forward button.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14168/live-cd-installer-gets-stuck-with-a-grayed-out-forward-button)

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu to a computer, alongside Windows XP using a partition. I set up the partition using the installer, and the setup seemed to be working properly. But, as the installation neared completion, it appeared to have stopped. I am currently looking at the menu for customising my Username/Password, and at the bottom the installer says "Ready when you are...". And, I cannot use the skip button, nor can I click the forward button to continue. Also, there appears to be an error log, if that would help.

Does anyone know how to fix this(or, if there is a problem at all)? Would it be unsafe to reset my computer during this phase of installation?

This is my first time setting up a computer to use Ubuntu, so I really have no idea if there's something I should be doing to fix this.

Comment: @Jorge Thank you so much, It appears to be working again! I'll see what happens now...

Comment: Ends up this is a dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14168/live-cd-installer-gets-stuck-with-a-grayed-out-forward-button

Answer (score 0):

I think you are meant to create a password and it won't let you proceed without one for Unix security reasons

Comment: I made sure I filled out all the fields properly. I made a username, and the passwords match. It simply will not let me continue, though. Would it be a problem if the password was rated only fair?