# Ubuntu install problem: "USB disconnect address 2"

Tags: 10.10, installation

I am installing ubuntu 10.10 and i am having problem in "Who are you?" section. How long will it take to install. i have been waiting for more than 20 minutes. and still i am not being able to click forward button.

in ready when you are ... console i am getting message

```
curr DATE ubuntu kernel: [ 684.152061 ] usb 5-1:USB disconnect address 2
```

whats happening i have no idea, but live stick is working fine. I am installing for USB drive and i have internet turned off

edit:: now i am getting message

```
curr Date ubuntu: CRON[9268]: (root) CMD (start -q anacron || :)
```

for past 15 minutes

updates:: 
while booting from pendrive named Tamkor(china made don't know) i got error message Boot Mgr Missing and i was using unetbootin-windows-494 to make bootable

Comment: This is probably: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14168/installer-gets-stuck-with-a-grayed-out-forward-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm a newbie.*

I had a similar problem a few days ago where the installation would apparently "hang" at around 85% progress. It would work on the disk for a while, then nothing, then work a little again. **I killed the machine and started the installation all over,** and this time the installation went quickly without long pauses.

If you don't have anything to lose (and don't have other operating systems or boot partitions on that disk), then I'd recommend that you just power the machine off and on again, and start over. The installation is so quick (when it works) that it doesn't really pay off to wait too long when it seems to hang.

If the installer won't complete next time either, then perhaps there's something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To get passed that long wait, you need to have everything in lower case. Yeah, its weird. even if you don't want a password, you still need one, also weird.