# Hangs up on install "Who are you" -- Dell Inspiron 1150

Tags: installation, dell, inspiron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installer gets stuck with a grayed out forward button.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14168/installer-gets-stuck-with-a-grayed-out-forward-button)

I'm installing to a Dell Inspiron 1150 from a CD. I get to the window labeled "Who are you?," and enter info into all the fields. The prompt at the bottom says "Ready when you are..." The BACK button is available, but the FORWARD button is grayed out. I tried going BACK, and I tried reentering the info, and I tried restarting the install, but I can't get it past this screen.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your username is all in lower case - this is a problem on all operating systems.