# Trying to install ubuntu netbook 10.10 but it hangs on the "who are you" screen

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, installation, aspire

I have an "Acer Aspire ONE ZG8 Netbook", and i wanted to install Ubuntu on it for quite some time, but it won't install. It has wiped windows from my hard drive already, so i can't go back to the horrible "Win7 Starter Edition", that came with this Netbook.

I would really love a way to fix this, but right now i am using the "Try Ubuntu / Live CD" aspect just so I have use of the Internet. No idea if I will be able to download an older version and try again from here or what to do.

Any help would be great.

Comment: When you select 'Try Ubuntu' and boot into the live cd environment does it prompt you to install additional hardware drivers?

Comment: maybe you are [affected by this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14168/installer-gets-stuck-with-a-grayed-out-forward-button)?

Comment: As takkat says, please rule these solutions out : [installer gets stuck...](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14168/installer-gets-stuck-with-a-grayed-out-forward-button)

Answer (score 1):

Are you installing from a usb key? If possible, try another key. I had the same issue and tried another usb key, which worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You might try waiting for the installation to end before you click **Next** and enter personal data.

I've tried to install 10.10 Desktop several times 'till I discovered that patience actually pays off ;]