# Installer stuck at "Ready when you are"

Tags: 11.04, installation

I had problems with my ubuntu installation, so I tried to reinstall from the cd i had for ubuntu....it asks me first if i want to **upgrade 11.04 to 11.04 or do a new installation**. I selected new and I enter the time zone, and then come to the point where it asks me for the user-id, it does it's thing and then I get the message....**Ready when you are**.....but only the back button works, the forward button is greyed out. So, I turned off the computer and started again, this time, trying to upgrade 11.04 to 11.04 and it comes and stops at the exact same point. I have it opened right now by chosing try ubuntu and from there I went in to install ubuntu 11.04 and I am at the window **allocate drive space**....(I had windows vista also on the previous install) so there are a few partitions and I don't know which one to select to do this correct. any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

this is what my allocate drive space says currently....

```
Device      type    mount point format      size    used
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1   ntfs                    7669MB  6724MB
/dev/sda2   ntfs                    101093MB    16170MB
/dev/sda7   ext4                    84875MB 3563MB
/dev/sda8   swap                    2128MB  0MB
/dev/sda6   swap                    2130MB  0MB
/dev/sda5   swap                    2135MB  0MB

and below that I have 5 buttons
New Partition table… Add… Change.... Delete Revert
below that is
Device for boot loader installation.....which one do I choose from below
/dev/sda ATA Toshiba MK2035GS(200GB)
/dev/sda1 Windows REcovery Environment(loader)
/dev/sda2 Windows Vista (loader)
/dev/sda7 Ubuntu 11.04(11.04)
```

Comment: To set things clear, you want to keep the windows vista as a dual boot or is it just a partition with files at the moment?

Comment: I'd like to keep dual boot, but if it is not an option, I'd rather have ubuntu over windows vista. also, I just took a screenshot of the partition. how can I upload it here

Comment: Find the answer [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1854/when-can-we-link-to-pictures-direct-ie-posting-imghttp-ubuntuone-com-mypic7)

Comment: oh I guess I don't have enough reputation yet to do that, so I have edited the original post with the text info

Comment: link the URL in a comment and one of us can post it for you.

Comment: The boot loader goes to the MBR of sda, that way ubuntu can manage if you will boot to windows or start linux up. About your partitions, well, when you are installing you have the choice of "remove current linux" don't you? Thats the one you want, let the installer do its magic and you will be able to boot both, if not there is always a way out ;)

Comment: ok, I am starting the install instead of try ubuntu process again. I shall write the steps I am following as I do so. I have 4 options 1. Erase Ubunut 11.04 and reinstall (which is what I ran and it got stuck). 2. Upgrade Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.04 (tried that also) 3. erase everything and reinstall 4. something else.

Comment: I chose 1. Erase Ubuntu 11.04 and reinstall, and it is progressing with Copying files

Comment: ok, and it stalls....with the message , Ready when you are....

Comment: can someone please help me fix this...is this an Ubuntu bug?

Comment: @brunopereira81, can you please tell me what the way out is..

Comment: Post a link to the image so we can see what is happening with you, i'm trying to figure this out on a vbox.

Comment: unless I get it installed I can't send the screenshot. but on this page, the screenshot for 'Who are you' is exactly where mine stops. the only difference is my Forward button is grayed out. here's the page http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/04/23/how-to-install-ubuntu-11-04-from-usb-or-cd/

Comment: Aha! Try this, make sure your username doesn't have a capital letter or dash in it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14168/installer-gets-stuck-with-a-grayed-out-forward-button

Comment: I have one word as my username....oh no, you know what the problem was - I had left the password blank, darn it.....I reformatted my hard drive and I have lost my Windows Vista now....

Comment: dam, sorry for you loss

Comment: oh well, you live, you learn....thanks for your and Jorge's help...his hint helped me :-)

Answer (score 2):

The installer may have stopped because it waits for input, or more precisely, correct input. Make sure the username and the computer name have no spaces and other non-alphanumeric characters in them, except the dash (-).

As for the partition, it looks like /dev/sda7 is the only candidate. Needless to say, a clean install will most likely overwrite everything on that partition, so backup if the files you need.

Comment: This is the correct answer for what was happening here ;)

Comment: your comment came a little late mike, thanks regardless....

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to dual boot, ubuntu asks in the installer if you want to install ubuntu besides window which is the first option and will divide the hard drive to semi half half.  If you went through the installer already its possible that you might have messed up windows and this option dual booting and letting the installer do it for you wont work.

Also if you do install ubuntu on the whole drive the volume labels and storage number will disappear. so windows vista or whatever version won't install because in the windows installer it will ask you that their is no partition available such as C: D: whatever: and storage is _: but you can make a partition in ubuntu and fix it with gparted for windows to be installed there. The only down side is that you have to reinstall ubuntu and now make sure you choose install besides windows. Just mentioning in case you wanted to have dual boot with vista just in case. Its doable.