# Why can't I get past choosing username and password when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installer gets stuck with a grayed out forward button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14168/installer-gets-stuck-with-a-grayed-out-forward-button)

I have started installing Ubuntu, and the screen has frozen at the point where I am asked to choose a username and password.

I cannot click **Continue**. I *can* click **Back**, but that's it.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu so I can use it as a fully-fledged OS. This problem occurs while installing it from the live CD/DVD/USB, *not* while booting or testing Ubuntu from the live media.