# Can't continue after filling the "Who are You" password window

Tags: installation

I'm using a USB to install 12.04.3 on my laptop and it seems to install all the way the process bar says its "all most done" I'm filling my name and password but after it stop loading the files it wont let me continue. the continue button wont click i could go back but i cant continue and it wont reboot letting me know that it all install.

Answer (score 0):

Your question may be a possible duplicate to this:

[Installer gets stuck with a grayed out forward button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14168/installer-gets-stuck-with-a-grayed-out-forward-button)

See if it answers your question.